# Diffrential equation $2{x^3}{y}{dy}+(1-{y^2})({x^2}{y^2}+{y^2}-1)dx=0$

Tags: calculus

How do I solve the given differential equation? $$2{x^3}{y}{dy}+(1-{y^2})({x^2}{y^2}+{y^2}-1)dx=0$$

It does not seem to resemble any of the standard forms I was taught in class. All I really need are some hints to get me started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Define $z=y^2-1$ and your differential equation simplifies a lot since $2ydy=dz$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, along with the substitution u=(1/z), I managed to solve the problem.

Comment: Great ! You got it and you are very welcome.